# Wordpress - SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, plugins, download

I have a problem with wordpress. When I want to do install of some plugin or update Wordpress to new version then I get error:

> Download failed. cURL error 77: Problem with the SSL CA cert

Path? Access rights?

I didn't change anything on my website. I have shared hosting.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue with OVH and a let's encrypt certificat. This is commun bug while you have a php version to 5.6. it's seems that is working fine with PHP 7.

Both, curl, file_get_contents and getimagesize running a file from my own server didn't work.

I correct the url and make it as a path on a direct URL.

```
https://example.com/file.css
```

Become

```
/home/example.com/file.css
```

And it works after.

Of course you will need to adapt your scripts with this to detect internal link that can cause the issue.

Comment: I have PHP 7, no cert on the domain.

Comment: If you don't have ssl, it's Logic (for an internal link). For external link, you maybe need to play with the header in your curl request ?

Comment: It's a standard operation in Wordpress, I think that problem could be on webhosting.